# Select whole paragraph in a RichTextBox based on the current Caret position

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` with `Multiline` set to `true`. It can contain multiple values, some of which are too long and get stretched into multiple lines but are treated as one line in RTB.

I'm trying to select the whole value, but when the text is stretched out, it will always select only the line in which I click.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
private void SelectLine(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    if (rtb.Lines.Length != 0)
    {
        int firstcharindex = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
        int currentline = rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstcharindex);
        string currentLineText = rtb.Lines[currentline];
        rtb.Select(firstcharindex, currentLineText.Length);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that `GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()` gets the index of the first character in the line I click into, instead of the index of the start of the actual value. However, in the Lines array, the value is represented as one line.

How can I modify this code to select the whole value regardless of how it's stretched out over multiple lines in the `RichTextBox ?

Comment: Why are you selecting lines in the first place? Just select: `rtb.Select(firstCharIndexOfMyMultilineValue, totalLengthOfMyMultilineValue);`

Comment: I dont know how to get index of whole value. `GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()` returns index of the line im currently in

Comment: Maybe you could search for actual line ends with [`rtb.Find("\r", startIndex, options)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-richtextbox-find(system-string-system-int32-system-windows-forms-richtextboxfinds)).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes A RichTextBox doesn't contain `\r` chars. It would be (kind of) different in case of a TextBox (or handling the more generic TextBoxBase)

Comment: @Jimi Yes thats exactly what i mean. And thats my problem - I need to Select logical lines but RichTextBox has only methods to get indexes of physical lines. So when i click on second physical line its still the same logical line so I get wrong index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Lines[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines) Property of the TextBoxBase returns the logical lines (lines of text separated by a line feed, `\n` or a Carriage Return + a Line Feed, `\r\n`).
The [GetLineFromCharIndex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getlinefromcharindex) method returns the physical line (wrapped text inside a container).

If you want to select the whole paragraph (logical line) that contains the caret, you have to look for its boundaries, i.e., the `\n` chars.
A RichTextBox only uses `\n` (`\r` chars are removed when you add / paste / set text that contains any), a TextBox uses `\r\n`.

For example:

I'm using `TextBoxBase` as the Type parameter, so you can use this method with both a RichTextBox and a TextBox (both derive from `TextBoxBase`). You could turn it into an extension method.

```
void SelectCurrentParagraph(TextBoxBase tbox) {
    var firstParagraphIndex = tbox.Text.LastIndexOf("\n", tbox.SelectionStart) + 1;

    var trim = tbox is RichTextBox ? 0 : 1;
    var lastParagraphIndex = tbox.Text.IndexOf("\n", tbox.SelectionStart) - trim;

    if (lastParagraphIndex < 0) lastParagraphIndex = tbox.TextLength;
    tbox.Select(firstParagraphIndex, lastParagraphIndex - firstParagraphIndex);
}
```

BTW, if you're using, e.g., a Button to call this method, remember to set the `HideSelection` Property of the RichTextBox / TextBox to `false`.